# Check which processes are running from a given location in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh, ps

I have the following directories structure:

```
./folder1
  -- file1.py
  -- file2.py

./folder2
  -- file3.py
  -- file4.py

etc...

useless_file_a.py
useless_file_b.py
```

I am trying to write a `bash` script to know which of `file[i].py` processes are running. By running, I mean to see the process displayed as a result of the `ps -elf` command.

My idea is to:

1. Loop through those `folder[i]` and list the `.py` files available. For this step I can use:

   `find . -type f -name "*.py" -mindepth 2`
2. Check running processes that matches the names found in 1.

   I know about the `ps -elf` command and I would like to link it to step 1.

I am struggling to come up with something for this last step.

The whole point of this script is to alert me if one of those `.py` scripts are not running. As there can be many scripts and many folders, I want to automatize this process.

**NB**: The `useless_file_*.py` are in the `pwd` and are not relevant for me.

Comment: Do you really mean _running_ (in the sense of a process state), or do you mean _which processes exist_ (including, for instance, processes in the state _suspended_)?  See [here](https://jaxenter.com/linux-process-states-173858.html) for an overview of the process states.

Comment: Thanks, I have just updated the question. I mean running when I do `ps -elf`

Comment: Do you see them with `ps -elf`? If yes, I would process like this: (1) Collect all the process names you are interested, into an array. (2) Run your `ps` command  and loop over its output. (3) For each line see whether the process name mentioned here, matches an element of your array.

Comment: yes I do see them with `ps -elf`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible, generally, to find out "if a script is running". This information is not stored anywhere.

You can check if the string that is the filename is in the command line arguments of processes:

```
for f in */*.py; do
   pgrep -f "$(basename "$f")"
done
```

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks. Sorry by "running" I meant a process that you can see when doing `ps`. Will update the question accordingly

Comment: How to output the `file[i].py` name of the process instead of its `pid` ?

Comment: Name of the process is python. It's an argument. Just `if pgrep ....; then echo "$(basename "$f")"; done` or `ps $(pgrep ..)`